# Jquery: Turn this into a function? scrolling body to #id with optional offset and speed etc

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, target, scrolltop

I'm trying to create a function that i can use over and over. I have it set up so if the link points to an ID on the page that is an H2, then it will scroll to the target with an offset of + 10px, then fade an arrow in and out a few times. But if the link points to the #footer element, then it should scroll down the page, then once landing at the target it changes the background color from a blue to a light blue a few times, then back to blue.

What would be the most efficient way to make a function with this? So i don't keep repeating code?

```
var target = $(this).attr("href"); ...............
        if ($(target).is('#foot_wrapper')) {
            $('html,body').delay(600).animate({
                     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - $(window).height() + 139
            }, 1500, function () {
                $('#bottomline').animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#2f5e9f"
                }, 300).animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#76acfb"
                }, 300)

            }) 
        } else if ($(target).is('#header')) { etc. etc. etc.
```

using some of my code above, something like this, i think...:

```
function scrollToAnimate (ifTargetIsThis, yOffset, speed, callback)
```

ifTargetIsThis = `#foot_Wrapper`

yOffset = `- $(window).height() + 139`

speed = `1500`

Obviously i need some help making this function, or if you think you could make it more efficient than my little example above, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward, you're probably overthinking it:

```
var scrollToAnimate = function ( yOffset, speed, callback ) {
  $('html,body').delay(speed*0.4).animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top + yOffset
  }, speed, callback});
}
```

Notice I left the `ifTargetIsThis` out of the arguments because I think that should still happen outside the function, which you would call like so:

```
if ($(target).is('#foot_wrapper')) {
  scrollToAnimate( -$(window).height() + 139, 1500, function () {
    $('#bottomline').animate({backgroundColor: "#2f5e9f"}, 300)
                    .animate({backgroundColor: "#76acfb"}, 300);
  });
} else if ($(target).is('#header')) {
  scrollToAnimate( etc, etc, etc );
}
```